# how to pivot a simple joined data set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query:

```
select MONTH(x.status_date) m
, YEAR(x.status_date) y
from [XREF_WET_MASTER] x
join F_ACCESSION_DAILY f
on x.accession_id=f.accession_id
pivot (count(*) for f.REQUISITION_TYPE in ([req1],[req2],[req3])
) as CountofThatTypeofReq
```

and i am getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '*'.

on the `count(*)` line

here are the expected results:

```
+---+------+------+------+------+
| m |  y   | req1 | req2 | req3 |
+---+------+------+------+------+
| 1 | 2010 |   34 |    3 |    6 |
| 2 | 2010 |   56 |    6 |    0 |
| 3 | 2010 |    5 |   33 |    4 |
+---+------+------+------+------+
```

I would be most grateful for any guidance on this pivot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `count(*)`, you should be able to use something like the following:

```
select *
from
(
  select MONTH(x.status_date) m
    , YEAR(x.status_date) y
    , f.REQUISITION_TYPE
    , f.accession_id
  from [XREF_WET_MASTER] x
  join F_ACCESSION_DAILY f
    on x.accession_id=f.accession_id
) src
pivot 
(
  count(REQUISITION_TYPE) 
  for REQUISITION_TYPE in ([req1],[req2],[req3])
) as CountofThatTypeofReq
```

Comment: Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The column 'ACCESSION_ID' was specified multiple times for 'CountofThatTypeofReq'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "x.status_date" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "x.status_date" could not be bound.

Comment: i do not wnat to select these two     , f.REQUISITION_TYPE
    , f.accession_id

Comment: when i remove those, i am getting INVALID COLUMN on this:   count(REQUISITION_TYPE) 
  for REQUISITION_TYPE in ([req1],[req2],[req3])

Comment: You are only selecting them for the `PIVOT`, you can remove the `accession_id `. They will not appear in the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of count(*), according to the docs, it would [appear you need to specify a specific column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to pivot on, so try:

```
select MONTH(x.status_date) m
, YEAR(x.status_date) y
from [XREF_WET_MASTER] x
join F_ACCESSION_DAILY f
on x.accession_id=f.accession_id
pivot (count(f.accession_id) for f.REQUISITION_TYPE in ([req1],[req2],[req3])
) as CountofThatTypeofReq
```

... or something similar.

Comment: Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The column 'SPECIMEN_ID' was specified multiple times for 'CountofThatTypeofReq'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "x.status_date" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "x.status_date" could not be bound.